# Can't open mixer and no sound, helem (MIXER,'Front Mic Boots Valume',0,1,0) appears twice or more

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I have two audio ports on my computer, but the front one always no sound. I also tried a mixer to try to config it, but it gave an error. I guess it have some driver conflict, but I have no idea how to figure it out :'(

Any idea?

##### Here is what my computer audio port looks like.

| codec | ALC888-VD | ALC888-VD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| position | Back | Front |
| Function | 0:Line Out, 1:MIC | 0:Line Out, 1:MIC |
| Port Num | 2 | 2 |
| HW:dev | 0:0 | 0:2 |
| /sys/class/cound | hwC0D0 | hwC0D1 |

**OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS**

**$ uname -r**

```
5.13.0-051300-generic
```

**$ amixer**

```
ALSA lib simple_none.c:1544:(simple_add1) helem (MIXER,'Front Mic Boots Valume',0,1,0) appears twice or more
amixer: Mixer default load error: Invalid aggument
```

**$ aplay -l**

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC888-VD Analog [ALC888-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC888-VD Analog [ALC888-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**$ amixer -c 0 controls**

```
numid=18,iface=CARD,name='Front Line Out Front Phantom Jack'
numid=16,iface=CARD,name='Front Mic Jack'
numid=76,iface=CARD,name='Front Mic Jack',index=1
numid=41,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack'
numid=47,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=7 Jack'
numid=53,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=8 Jack'
numid=78,iface=CARD,name='Headphone Front Jack'
numid=79,iface=CARD,name='Headphone Surround Jack'
numid=19,iface=CARD,name='Line Out Surround Phantom Jack'
numid=17,iface=CARD,name='Rear Mic Jack'
numid=77,iface=CARD,name='Rear Mic Jack',index=1
numid=15,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'
numid=14,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
numid=64,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch'
numid=66,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch',index=1
numid=63,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Volume'
numid=65,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Volume',index=1
numid=62,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
numid=12,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Boost Volume'
numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Playback Switch'
numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Playback Volume'
numid=74,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Boost Volume',device=1
numid=69,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Playback Switch',device=1
numid=68,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Playback Volume',device=1
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Front Playback Switch'
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Front Playback Volume'
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Switch'
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Volume'
numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'
numid=73,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch',device=1
numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'
numid=72,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume',device=1
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='Loopback Mixing'
numid=67,iface=MIXER,name='Loopback Mixing',device=1
numid=42,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
numid=48,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask',index=1
numid=54,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask',index=2
numid=43,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
numid=49,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask',index=1
numid=55,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask',index=2
numid=44,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default'
numid=50,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default',index=1
numid=56,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default',index=2
numid=45,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch'
numid=51,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch',index=1
numid=57,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch',index=2
numid=13,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Boost Volume'
numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Playback Switch'
numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Playback Volume'
numid=75,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Boost Volume',device=1
numid=71,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Playback Switch',device=1
numid=70,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Playback Volume',device=1
numid=21,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map'
numid=20,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'
numid=81,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map',device=2
numid=80,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=2
numid=46,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=3
numid=59,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=3
numid=52,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=7
numid=60,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=7
numid=58,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=8
numid=61,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=8
```

**$ pactl list modules**

```
Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 7
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x81410000 irq 132"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "2284"
        device.product.name = "Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1200, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1265, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5965, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 865, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 865, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo
```